# iPhone Function: How to rebuild this functionality?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to rebuild this functionality:

http://www.iphonetavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/screenshot_buttons.jpg

That means, when I click a button on my ButtonBar, I want a popup (maybe with this nice slide effect from bottom to top) and a few Buttons with more detail choices....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a UIActionSheet.

The Apple Documentation can be found [here](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/).

A blog post on how to use it can be found [here](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/).